# Prove that the numbers are different

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be an integer that is not divisible by any square greater than $1$. Denote by $x_m$ the last digit of the number $x^m$ in the number system with base $n$. If a period $t$ of $x_m$ is relatively prime to $m$, prove that $0_m,1_m\ldots,(n-1)_m$ are different numbers.

**Attempt:**

We are looking at \begin{align*}0^m &\equiv 0 \pmod{n} \\1^m &\equiv 1 \pmod{n} \\2^m &\equiv b_1 \pmod{n} \\&\vdots\\(n-1)^m &\equiv b_{n-2} \pmod{n}\end{align*} but we know that $x^t \equiv x \pmod{n}.$ But since $m$ and $t$ are relatively prime, no $m$th power of an integer between $1$ and $n$, exclusive, can be congruent to itself.

It doesn't look like pigeonhole principle works well here so we might need a stronger result.

Comment: What do you mean by "a period of $x_m$"?

Comment: @ErickWong For example, the periods of powers of $2$ modulo $10$ are $4k$ since $2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod{10},2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{10},2^3 \equiv 8 \pmod{10},2^4 \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$.

Comment: Sure but you haven't said what a period of $x_m$ means.  When $x=1$ then all integers are periods of $x_m$ so the condition is trivial.  Notice that $x$ does not appear anywhere in the conclusion!